# Blue-striped boot screen after uninstall gnome

Tags: boot, gnome

I installed Gnome 3.8 like in link (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gnome-3-8-ppa-for-ubuntu-gnome) is described. I installed it, didn't liked it so uninstalled it as there is written. I had some problems with login session which I solved but booting screen is no more purple with Ubuntu logo but blue with strippes. And I think my pc is little slower. Is here anybody who knows how to change this booting screen?

Answer (score 0):

The blue stripes you are seeing is actually the boot splash, which is configured through the plymouth themes. You can change it by executing `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` in terminal and selecting a different theme.

Comment: This may well be the answer, but it needs a bit more information so that anyone else with a similar problem can follow the answer. If you could add a bit more information, to your answer it would be better.